# Upload attachment with SharePoint list item using REST API in .Net Core project

Tags: .net-core, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, attachment, rest

I have created a .net core project and implemented a GET/POST request with a SharePoint list with reference to the below link.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/consume-sharepoint-online-csom-rest-api-with-dotnet-core-3-1/

Now, I need to upload an attachment with the SharePoint list item using REST API in the .Net Core project.

Can anyone help me with the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rest API endpoint for uploading attachment to list item is:

```
/_api/lists/GetByTitle('<listName>')/items(<itemId>)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='<attachmentName>')
```

Reference:https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/257779/add-attachment-to-a-list-item-using-rest-api